# Ubuntu-to-Android Cross Compile linking for clock_gettime

Tags: android, c, linux, gcc, makefile

I recently developed a project in C which makes use of the  function clock_gettime() in linux. The linking for this on my Ubuntu desktop is achieved using the linker flag:

```
gcc -lrt foo.c
```

I was excited to read that I could cross-compile my project for the Android in the post below.

http://benno.id.au/blog/2007/11/13/android-native-apps

I've tried this on trivial projects though using the command:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static foo.c -o foo
```

Rather than the command:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static foo.c -o foo
```

referred to in the link, and they do indeed compile and link fine, but when I try with my project requiring clock_gettime() and the linking:

```
-ltr
```

It fails with:

```
undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
```

I've read that library specified by -lrt doesn't exist for the Android, and I've found posts other places claiming that folks are using clock_gettime() on Android projects, but I haven't been able to find the right library to link to for this.  Can anyone tell me what I need to link to for the ARM to make this work?

Or make any other suggestions as to alternatives that will work on the Android.

I am very much interested in leveraging my existing makefiles from my Desktop linux projects to what extent I can, but reconfiguring them to work with the cross-compile tool chain if possible, so any suggestions which would allow for that would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're statically linking, you'd presumably need `gcc -static foo.c -lrt`  , not `gcc -static -lrt foo.c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's "bionic" C library has a wrapper for the `clock_gettime()` syscall.  If you build using the Android NDK you'll get that automatically.  Otherwise you need to add a bionic library to your toolchain somehow.

Alternatively, you could call the syscall directly via assembly (from memory, the first argument goes in R0, the second in R1, you put the syscall number in R7, issue "SWI $0" and find the result code in R0).

Alternatively: why are you bothering with clock_gettime?  Is there any reason you can't simply use gettimeofday()?

Comment: I've been away from my desk this weekend so I haven't had a chance to run this down just yet, but I'm looking into adding the bionic library to my tool-chain and I'll comment back soon on that count.

_Alternatively: why are you bothering with clock_gettime? Is there
any reason you can't simply use gettimeofday()?_

What guided that decision for me was this note in the `gettimeofday()` man page: 

_SVr4, 4.3BSD. POSIX.1-2001 describes gettimeofday() but not
settimeofday(). POSIX.1-2008 marks gettimeofday() as obsolete,
recommending the use of clock_gettime(2) instead._

Comment: Indeed, clock_gettime() is a newer and more featureful API.  But it's not supported by what you have.  On the other hand, gettimeofday() is an ancient API that works everywhere, and it's not going anywhere (it's "obsolete", not "deprecated").  If all you want is the current system time, just use it.

Comment: Well, I'm still trying to work through the ins and outs of the Android NDK process, but so far switching to `gettimeofday()` has at least been a good work around for the `-lrt` dependency!  Thanks!